# C# SQL BulkCopy datetime insert issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sqlbulkcopy

I'm having an issue bulk inserting a data table containing a C# `DateTime` object into a SQL Server database, and keep getting the following error:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column

I ran a stack trace to see what the table was trying to insert (picture below)

[Datatable insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDy5I.png)

Here's the code I'm using to parse the date

```
 SInstance s = new SInstance {                    
                Timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0],"yyyy-MM-dd",null),
               //other property initializations                   
            };
```

where

```
values[0] = "2018-08-08"
```

Most of the other answers say to manually configure the data table with the appropriate formats, but these tables are generated dynamically at run-time using class properties so hard-coding anything is out of the question. Here's the code for the bulk copy snippet

```
DataTable dt = DBOHelper.GenerateDataTable(dbObjects);

using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = _database.BulkCopySQL())
{
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = table;
    sqlBulk.BatchSize = commitBatchSize;

    try
    {
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        dt.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AuditEngine.Instance.LogError("DatabaseEngine", "SQLBulkInsert", e.Message);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and table generator function:

```
public static DataTable GenerateDataTable<T>(DBOCollection<T> dBOCollection)
        where T : DbObject
{
    DataTable dt = GenerateEmptyDataTable<T>();

    List<PropertyInfo> props = GetDBODataMemberProperties<T>();

    foreach (DbObject dbo in dBOCollection)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            row[i] = props[i].GetValue(dbo);
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dt;
}

public static DataTable GenerateEmptyDataTable<T>()
        where T : DbObject
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    List<PropertyInfo> properties = GetDBODataMemberProperties<T>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {              
        dt.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Everything works fine for objects without date fields, but for some reason it throws an error with all the date formats I've tried. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `it throws an error` What error?

Comment: Is it because you are converting to Timestamp and not System.DateTime? I'm not sure where this line `Timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0],"yyyy-MM-dd",null)` is

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Timestamp is a property name of an object in an ORM scheme, not the type of object being written to. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TimeStamp`, time stamp will result in string, meaning that if you will execute the following:

```
Timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0],"yyyy-MM-dd",null)
```

You will get a string. Just for reference, here is a method to generate time stamp:

```
public static String GetTimestamp(this DateTime value)
{
    return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
}
```

All you need to do is change it to:

```
DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(values[0],"yyyy-MM-dd",null);
```

I'd recommend:

```
DateTime date; 
 if(DateTime.TryParseExact(values[0], "yyyy-MM-dd", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date)
{
   //succeeded, date contains the value
}
else
{
  //error
}
```

Comment: Sorry Barr J I didn't give enough information in the question, ""Timestamp" is the name of a property not a class in this context. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to generate a list of property names at run-time, and then map those to the SqlBulkCopy object (this only works if the database column names and property names match)

```
DataTable dt = DBOHelper.GenerateDataTable(dbObjects, out List<string> propertyNames);

        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = _database.BulkCopySQL())
        {
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = table;
            sqlBulk.BatchSize = commitBatchSize;

            foreach (string s in propertyNames)
            {
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(s, s));
            }

            try
            {
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
                dt.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                AuditEngine.Instance.LogError("DatabaseEngine", "SQLBulkInsert", e.Message);
                return 0;
            }
        }
```